# How to print using color cartridge only?

Tags: windows-7, printer, colors

I am using Brother MFC-290C printer and recently it's black print head is spoiled. Therefore, it can't print black color properly. However, all the other color is still print perfectly fine.

So, is it possible to set the printer to print using color cartridge only? If there is black color, it will be using 3 colors to mix up making it into black.

Comment: Could try printing using only a just off black shade of grey...

Comment: Is there any option in the printer properties (button in the print dialog box), or in any application that came with the printer? If not, probably not.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any printer that will let you do this.

One reason why this is not possible is because the printer requires black in order to print the full range of colours. Using black as well as colours extends the printer's colour gamut. If you examine a printed colour page, you will see black dots in many colour areas.

The reverse, printing in black when out of colour can be done with some printers, but even that is fairly rare. Note also that, while black is printed with black ink only, many printers use some colour ink when printing greyscale - again to extend the range of printable greys.

EDIT
I should also add that, although theoretically a mix of 100% each cyan magenta & black should be black, in practice that will only produce a muddy brown or purple. In addition, that would mean black is printed as 300% ink, which would make the paper very wet and soggy - not to mention expensive.